# Firebase custom events with prescribed parameters

Tags: firebase

I want to setup an event called read_review for firebase. In this event, I want to send the parameters defined in firebase. Below I have added how we should send custom and defined events according to the Google document. How should I send the custom event name and defined parameters?

**recommended events**

```js
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

**custom events**

```js
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("image_name", name);
params.putString("full_text", text);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("share_image", params);
```

**my code**

```js
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("read_review", params);
```

Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your events are getting logged correctly and uploaded to server, enable verbose logging and use DebugView console.

The advantage of using the recommended event names and its parameters is that some of them have corresponding chart that you can view on dashboard page.

Any event name or parameter that is not in the recommended list is categorized as custom and can only be viewed in events page.

To answer your question, you may mix logging custom event name with recommended parameters or recommended event name with custom parameters.